# Syntax error in python code while trying in IDLE

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, syntax-error

This code works good in the editor but why I'm getting error while trying in IDLE 
Program:

```
>>>i=1
while i<=5:
    print(i)
    i+=1
print("end")
```

Output:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Expected Output:
1
2
3
4
5
end

Comment: read the python syntax

Comment: Yes I did, my question is why it is working fine in editor but not while putting directly in IDLE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IDLE is a python interpreter, it reads statements one by one.
You have 3 statements in there.

```
First: i = 1
Second: while i<=5:
    print(i)
    i+=1
Third: print("end")
```

You have to put each in separate lines.

```
>>> i = 1
>>> while i<=5:
    print(i)
    i+=1
else:
    print("end")



1
2
3
4
5
end
>>>
```

EDIT: For that you can use else with while.
else block will be executed when you exit loop properly(i.e. without break statement.)

Comment: I want that end at the end of the loop

Comment: Edited response.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use IDLE like "Press a button and run the script I copied into it" then perhaps you would be more comfortable with my answer.

With IDLE open "File" menu -> "New File" -> Copy your lines of code into here -> Press F5 -> Give your script a name -> It will then run in IDLE from the file and you can write multiple lines of code which are executed sequentially

[Screenshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30nBH.png)

Comment: Yes I did that but my question is why it is syntax error when typing print("end"), when I code this in C or C++ I will give this print("end") after the curly braces of the while loop so that I can get the output:1 2 3 4 5 end

Comment: IDLE expects statements to be written on each line, or multi-line statements to be multi-lined and tabbed correctly. Syntax errors can be caused by a number of things, missing characters like ) or } and also, like in your case, trying to execute more than one statement. I rarely use IDLE for this purpose unless I want to slowly go through the logic of a script.